# upload multiple images with form data android

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/08/16/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-one-request-along-with-other-string-parameters-in-android/) with uploading five images and some form data below is the code i used to implement task

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
    File file2 = new File(selectedPath2);
    File file3 = new File(selectedPath3);
    File file4 = new File(selectedPath4);
    File file5 = new File(selectedPath5);
    String urlString="http:url.com";

    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);
        FileBody bin1 = new FileBody(file1);
        FileBody bin2 = new FileBody(file2);
        FileBody bin3 = new FileBody(file3);
        FileBody bin4 = new FileBody(file4);
        FileBody bin5 = new FileBody(file5);

        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
        reqEntity.addPart("section", new StringBody("inventory"));
        reqEntity.addPart("action", new StringBody("new"));
        reqEntity.addPart("apron_id", new StringBody(stock_number_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("nickname", new StringBody(nick_name_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("location", new StringBody(location));
        reqEntity.addPart("manufacture", new StringBody(manufacture));
        reqEntity.addPart("core_material", new StringBody(core_material_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("color", new StringBody(color_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("Date_purchase", new StringBody(dop_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("UID_no", new StringBody(gtin_uid_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("serial", new StringBody(serial_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("Batch", new StringBody(batch_lot_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("Expiration", new StringBody(ed_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("garment_type", new StringBody(description_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("QTY", new StringBody(county_ele.getText().toString()));
        reqEntity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody(SignInActivity.user_id));

        if(selectedPath1!="NONE")
            reqEntity.addPart("image1", bin1);
        if(selectedPath2!="NONE")
            reqEntity.addPart("image2", bin2);
        if(selectedPath3!="NONE")
            reqEntity.addPart("image3", bin3);
        if(selectedPath4!="NONE")
            reqEntity.addPart("image4", bin4);
        if(selectedPath5!="NONE")
            reqEntity.addPart("image5", bin5);

        post.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        resEntity = response.getEntity();
        final String response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        if (resEntity != null) {
            Log.i("RESPONSE",response_str);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e("Debug", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }

    return resEntity.toString();
}
```

Images and from data seems to be sent but no data received at server following is the response and php script

**Response**
{"status":0,"date":" No section Found "}

**Php**

```
elseif($section=="inventory")
                {
                    if(empty($action))
                    {
                        $response=array("status"=>0,"data"=>"No action Found");
                        echo json_encode($response);
                        exit;
                    }
                    require_once("classes/class_inventory.php");
                    $inventory = new inventory();
                    switch($action)
                    {
                        case 'new':
                                $response=$inventory->action_inventory($_REQUEST);
                                echo json_encode($response);
                                exit;
                        case 'get':
                            $response=$inventory->get_inventory($_REQUEST);
                            echo json_encode($response);
                            exit;

                    }
                } else {
                $response=array("status"=>0,"date"=>" No section Found ");
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ttp`? Shouldn't it be `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: Then use it and run your app.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76191/discussion-on-question-by-manikanta-g-upload-multiple-images-with-form-data-andr).

Comment: @meagar. Objection! You removed the conversation i had with OP. I'm pretty amazed that you removed my history. I spend hours here and you throw it away. That's not what I'm here for. A slam in the face. You moved -well tried to move it- to chat. But instead OP opened another thread about this problem. Now i can not even refer to what i already said to OP. This does feel very bad.

Comment: @greenapps Comments are not for extended discussion. They are temporary, and you should *assume* that they will be thrown away. If you have important information relevant to the question or answer, you need to put it in the question or answer, otherwise it may be lost.